# Duplicate questions, each with answers

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-to-choose-at-least-half-of-everything) and [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/100-bags-of-apples-beetroots-and-cakes) are essentially the same.
*Even if you disagree with the assessment that these two example questions are not similar enough to be duplicates, imagine the case with two very similar questions.* 
 When duplicate questions are found, ordinarily one would be closed as a duplicate, but at this point both questions have answers. What is considered the correct course of action in the case where two questions are considered duplicates of each other but both have answers submitted?

> 1. Vote to close the question that was asked second
> 2. Vote to close the question that received an answer second
> 3. Leave both open
> 4. Alternative options?

Comment: In general, I would vote to close the one with fewer, less-complete answers as a duplicate of the other. But I don't think these two questions are the same.

Comment: I would close the newest one. Would you like to see your question closed because another user posted a similar question after your? I guess no! Also, don't forget that closed doesn't mean deleted: closed questions still exist, the reputation gained isn't lost, simply you can't add new answers to it.

Comment: We need to get this question answered: what are we going to do about [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17389/who-is-the-fifth-child) and [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/what-was-her-name)?